# Grey border after editing questions with E key

Tags: bug, edits, keyboard-shortcuts

I have noted that if I edit a question using the <kbd>E</kbd> key I always get a grey border even after edit is finished

1. During edit: Expectable

[image: During edit]

2. After edit: Perhaps undesirable

[image: After edit]

3. Original or after F5

[image: After F5]

Is this a bug in SO front end or a desired behaviour? Hitting F5 restores page view

---

Edit

Well, the other question helps but is not a complete duplicate.

From that I see gray border is not a bug but a feature at least. A feature I didn't know of.

I am here first because I didn't know that it was part of a feature, so I thought this was a bug on the beginning.

Now it's just a matter of deciding whether the Edit key should make a visual selection or not, and/or reset it. At least to be consistent with mouse edits. If I use mouse I cannot "select" a post. If I could see this gray border when hovering posts it would have been easier to understand.

Comment: So, completing / aborting the edit should reset the selection? Why?

Comment: `At least to be consistent with mouse edits. If I use mouse I cannot "select" a post. If I could see this gray border when hovering posts it would have been easier to understand.`  Couldn't disagree more.  I don't use the keyboard shortcuts, but when using them, you have to know what is selected so you know you the key action you take is applied to the correct post.  If you press `E` when you have 3 different answers in your screen, which edit window should it open?  With a mouse, you know exactly which post you are editing since you had to click the edit link.